# How to get a json file with jQuery $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm making some university exam tests that ask me to get a JSON file from the url of an href in a object. After this I need to dynamically change the html with the information on the JSON file, so I guess I need to use $.ajax() or $.get() method.

I found several codes here on stack overflow but nothing seems to work for me, I can make my code to work only with $.load() method, while every other method does nothing, also the .addClass(), .removeClass() and event.preventDefault() works fine.

Here is my code:
js -> between script tags at the start of the page:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
     $("nav li a").click(function(event)
     {
      $("nav li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");


      $("#ris").load($(this).attr('href')); //this work

      $.ajax({url: $(this).attr('href'), dataType: "json",  //this give the alert
       success: function(result)
        {$("#ris").html(result);},
       error: function(){alert("Error");}
      });

      $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(json) { //this doesn't work
          $("#ris").html(json);
      });

      $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function(json){ //this doesn't work
        $("#ris").html(json);});

      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

html: I'm putting only the nav item here, #ris is at the end of the page

```
  <nav>
    <li><a href="./Asia.json">Asia</a></li>
    <li><a href="./Europa.json">Europa</a></li>
    <li><a href="./America.json">America</a></li>
    <li><a href="./Africa.json">Africa</a></li>
  </nav>
```

For now I'm just putting the result in #ris to see if it works. But I can't understand why I can't have a working get call with any method.

EDIT: the server never receive the GET request of JSON files. (server log)

Comment: What do you see in the developer console?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

You should post a data like an api and read response like below;

```
$.post("your_json_response_address", {"you_can_post":"anything"}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $("#ris").html(data);
    //code what you want...
})
```

Comment: The test asks to use a GET request